# navigate to repeater item by given id in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

In my userReply.aspx ,

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptReply" DataSource="mySqlDataSource">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table width="100%" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10">
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
                   <span style="margin-top:10px;display:block;">
                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Reply") %></span>
                        <br />
                  <span style="color: #0099CC; width: auto; height: auto;background-color: #ECF5FF;">
                       <span style="color: #666666; font-size: x-small; font-style: italic;">
                  <span class="timestamp" id="time" runat="server">
                                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ReplyDate")%></span>, By <span 
                                     style="color: #0077CC;">
                                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "UserName") %>
                                </span></span></span>
                                ReplyID : <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ReplyID") %>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

And i call this page with "ReplyID" parameter pass ,

```
userReply.aspx?replyID=4
```

Data source(mySqlDataSource) for repeater(rptReply) has ReplyID 1,2,3,4,5 and 6 .
I want to directly navigate and automatically scroll to the repeater item which has replyID **4** .

Comment: Have you tried a simple anchor?

Answer (score 0):

When you navigate the page and use some scroll implementation in your page;

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   // your scroll function
 });
```

I found [this](http://flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) plugin to scroll any element in the page.